# How to get execution time in milliseconds format in Weka

Tags: time, weka, data-mining, execution-time

I am using WEKA jvm and trying to run generalized sequential pattern algorithm on my data. I want to get execution time in millisecond. How can I do it ?

Comment: Try using Java code.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly. this has nothing to do with weka. Remove that tag.

Put this at the beginning of your code

```
        long startTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
```

and at the end of your program,

```
        long endTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();
        long timeTook = endTime - startTime
        System.out.println("time took in milliseconds="+timeTook);
        System.out.println("time took in seconds="+timeTook/1000);
```

System class also has methods `currentTimeMillis()` and `nanoTime()`

But keep that in mind, if you're taking input from users. More user waits to enter the input, more the time taken will be displayed.